# How can I remove all spawned objects from the screen?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to make a simple dodging game which includes a pickup that falls from the top of the screen: "wpLaser"

When the player touches the pickup, I want all of the spawned projectiles ("default") on the screen to be removed (is this possible?)

The issue is that I want the projectiles to continue spawning after the pickup has been picked-up

Here is some of the code for reference:

```
local composer = require("composer")
local widget = require("widget")
local scene = composer.newScene()

local physics = require( "physics" ) -- Using physics for collision detections
physics.start()
physics.setGravity( 0, 0 )

-- Object group for removal
local objectGroup = display.newGroup()

-- Set Variables
_W = display.contentWidth; -- Get the width of the screen
_H = display.contentHeight; -- Get the height of the screen

function scene:create( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
```

Here are the projectiles that I want to be removed when the player touches the pickup:

```
-- Projectiles
    local numberDefault = 1 --local variable; amount can be changed

    local function clearDefault( thisDefault )
        display.remove( thisDefault ) ; thisDefault = nil
    end

    local function spawnDefault()
        for i=1,numberDefault do
            local default = display.newImage( "projectiles/default.png" )
            default.x = math.random( 0, _W )
            default.y = -100
            default.myName = "default"
            default.class = "default"

            physics.addBody( default, "dynamic", { density = 0, friction = 0, bounce = 0, isSensor = true, radius = 30 } )
            transition.to( default, { x = math.random( 0, _W ), y = 1200, time = 4000, onComplete = clearDefault } )

            objectGroup:insert( default )
        end
    end

    timerDefault = timer.performWithDelay( 250, spawnDefault, 0 )  -- spawn 1 every 250 units
```

And this is the pickup itself:

```
-- Laser power-up
    local numberWpLaser = 1 --local variable; amount can be changed

    local function clearWpLaser( thisWpLaser )
        display.remove( thisWpLaser ) ; thisWpLaser = nil
    end

    local function spawnWpLaser()
        for i=1,numberWpLaser do
            local wpLaser = display.newImage( "images/wpLaser.png" )
            wpLaser.x = math.random( 0, _W )
            wpLaser.y = -100
            wpLaser.myName = "wpLaser"

            physics.addBody( wpLaser, "dynamic", { density = 0, friction = 0, bounce = 0, isSensor = true, radius = 40 } )
            transition.to( wpLaser, { x = wpLaser.x, y = 1200, time = 5000, onComplete = clearWpLaser } )

            objectGroup:insert( wpLaser )

        end
    end

    timerWpLaser = timer.performWithDelay( 5000, spawnWpLaser, 0 )  -- spawn 1 every 5000 units

-- Collision detection events
    local function onCollision( event )
        if event.phase == "began" then -- event is only called when it begins (not when it ends)
            if ( event.object1.myName == "player" and event.object2.myName == "default") then
                print( "You Died" )
```

This is where I am having difficulty. When the player touches the pickup, I want all of the spawned objects on the screen to be removed BUT to continue to be spawned.
Currently, the projectiles are being removed, but I can't get them to start spawning again.

```
            elseif ( event.object1.myName == "player" and event.object2.myName == "wpLaser") then
                event.object2:removeSelf()
                transition.cancel( default )

                timer.pause( timerDefault )
                timer.pause( timerWpLaser )

                local pickupSound = audio.loadSound( "audio/pickup.mp3" )
                local pickupChannel = audio.play( pickupSound )

                local blank = display.newRect( _W/2, _H/2, _W, _H )
                blank.myName = "blank"
                transition.to( blank, { time = 800, alpha = 0, onComplete = clearblank } )

                objectGroup:removeSelf( )
                objectGroup = nil

                print( "Pickup" )
            end
        end
    end

Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onCollision )
end
```

Sorry about dumping all of the code here, if you need any confirmation about anything please ask.
Assistance is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every "250 units" you `spawnDefault` which adds objects to objectGroup. In your handler for "player touches the pickup", you set objectGroup to nil. So then you tell me, where is `spawnDefault` going to add objects to next time it runs?

Comment: So, are you saying that it's a mistake to be removing objectGroup? Is there an alternate way for me to remove the objects that are currently on the screen?

Comment: You have a desk with a box sitting on it. It contains toys. You want to remove the toys from the room, but you'll want to bring more toys in later. Do you take the toys out of the box? Or do you take the box out of the room? If you take the box out of the room, where will you put the new toys?

Comment: I understand what you are saying - that I shouldn't be removing objectGroup. But do you know another way for me to remove the projectiles?
I'm sorry, I'm not very experienced at coding.

Comment: After removing objectGroup you can recreate it again, or you can check if objectGroup is null before spawn a new projectile, if is null you can create it again.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but could you please show me how I could do that?

Comment: how did you create objectGroup in the first place?

Comment: `local objectGroup = display.newGroup()`

Comment: so do that again. but keep in mind, in the first place, it was 'local' to the file. when you recreate it again, it will be within a function; if it were 'local' in that function, then it would be a different variable than the one at the file level. so don't type local again. in general, don't type anything unless you know what it does, and if you knew what local did here, you wouldn't type it there.